# How to add cases across columns that meet a condition, within rows?

Tags: sql

I have data on household ownership of appliances, with one appliance per column, and data in the format of Y or N.  I want to generate a new column with the sum of appliances owned per household.  When I run the following script (SQLIte), I get an error message about syntax error near ")".  Please help - I've tried all sorts of syntax.

```
SELECT Household,
SUM((CASE WHEN Stove="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN Fridge="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN TV="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN Video="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN SatDish="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN Radio="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
(CASE WHEN FixPhone="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0) END) 
AS Appliances
FROM Assets
```

Comment: Have you tried query below?

Answer (score 1):

You need End with every case statement:
Try this:

```
SELECT Household,
SUM((CASE WHEN Stove="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN Fridge="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN TV="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN Video="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN SatDish="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN Radio="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
(CASE WHEN FixPhone="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 End))
AS Appliances
FROM Assets
Group By Household
```